# How to determine if document is a template?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to figure out if a document is a simple document (.doc, .docx, .docm) or a template (.dot, .dotx, .dotm).

I know there are several ways to figure this out (like check file extension), but I am looking for the most "safe" one.

My current guess is:

```vb
Private Function isTemplate(ByVal Doc As Document) As Boolean
    isTemplate = (Doc.FullName = Doc.AttachedTemplate.FullName)
End Function
```

This works as expected, but I would like to know if there is a more fashioned way to achieve this goal. Maybe some missing isTemplate property? dunno.

Why: I've created a code on a template to don't allow a user to save a file if it is not password protected. The code works like a charm, but it bores me when I am editing something in the template because it doesn't have a password.

Comment: in Excel you can use `if ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = xlTemplate`. I would have thought you could likewise detect `wdTemplate` formats in Word, but unfortunately, I can't find it in the Object Model.

Comment: That's a clever approach. The problem using the extension is that new files don't have extensions until saved the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to kmote, I found the solution.

Just check in the [SaveFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.saveformat.aspx) property if the document is a Template ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat.aspx) is the list of possible values for this property).

```vb
Private Function isTemplate(ByVal Doc As Document) As Boolean
  Select Case Doc.SaveFormat
    Case wdFormatTemplate, wdFormatDocument97, _
         wdFormatXMLTemplate, wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled, _
         wdFormatFlatXMLTemplate, wdFormatFlatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
      isTemplate = True
    Case Else
      isTemplate = False
  End Select
End Function
```