# ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled not working

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, save

I have the following code in my Word File:

...

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=savePathTEMPLATE & SaveFileName & ".dotm", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled
```

...

This is always running in an error, and no file is being created in the folder.

If I change the "wdFormatXMLTemplateMacroEnabled" to "wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled" then it works like a charm...

Could someone please explain me why this is not working? I really don't understand it...

Thank you very much

Comment: did u tried .docm ?

Comment: as it work for `wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled` it rules out problem with path and file name (and to some degree version also). Though it is a shot in dark,   [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643251/how-to-determine-if-document-is-a-template) or [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32237729/ms-word-saveas-check-maintain-compatibility-via-vba/32238515#32238515) may be worth to have a look.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question to add the ERROR information - without that we can't even begin to guess what the problem might be. Also provide the information contained in the variables `savePathTEMPLATE` and `SaveFileName`, please. What does the document contain? And are you able to save it manually as a template?